# moxtra - join the same chat - js api

Tags: javascript, chat

Is there a joinChat() in js api?  For meeting, there is a joinMeet() api (takes session_key as parameter).  I guess joinChat() will require session_id as parameter?  I did not find joinChat() in documentation.

I wish to have two users joining the same chat.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will need to use the Embed Binder/Chat SDK to embed the chat (both for the user who initiate the chat and the user who is part of the chat). When you initiate the chat you will get binder_id in your callback response.
2. For a user to be part of the chat he need to be added by the initiator. There are couple of options to add the user to be part of the chat

-- if using unique_id based authentication model you can pass the unique_id of the users as part of the "Moxtra.chat(options)" SDK call when initiating the chat.

-- Another option is to use the following REST API to add users to the chat using binder_id

```
POST https://api.moxtra.com/{binder_id}/addteamuser?access_token=[access_token]
{
    "users": [
    {
        "user": {
            "unique_id": "ssdfsdfsdf33434"
        }
    },
    {
        "user": {
            "unique_id": "rf131zadad22312"
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Got it.  I noticed that using the binder_id, the chat data seems to be persistent.  That is, the next time the users decide to chat, they will see the data from previous session.  Is there a way to create ephemeral chat session that is erased when the chat session is closed or when everyone left the chat session?